# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 75 path $.result

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit with Gson. The data from server is like:

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "result": {
        // ...
        "entity":[]
    }
}
```

And this is the part of POJO which is about ARRAY:

```
List<Entity> entity;
```

The error log:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 75 path $.result

I can't find what made the error. Please help me.

Comment: please post your code also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**MyPojo.java**

```
// Base Pojo class for conversion. 
public class MyPojo implements Serializable
{
    private Result result;

    private String code;

    public Result getResult ()
    {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult (Result result)
    {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getCode ()
    {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode (String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

**Result.java**

```
public class Result implements Serializable
{
    private String[] entity;

    public String[] getEntity ()
    {
        return entity;
    }

    public void setEntity (String[] entity)
    {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}
```

And I found [this](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/) page very helpful for converting JSON to POJO models.